# How to compare two string in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am Developing a web apps in Asp.net using vb.net language and i comparing two string using

> "=" and 
>   "String.Equals()"

but i get always false result

```
Dim decod As Decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder()
Dim totByt As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(Request("numType"))
Dim chrCount As Integer = decod.GetCharCount(totByt, 0, totByt.Length)
Dim deco_char(chrCount) As Char
decod.GetChars(totByt, 0, totByt.Length, deco_char, 0)
Dim str As New String(deco_char)

If str = "MO" Or str.Equals("Mo") Then
       //Do somthing     

End If
```

Please see my Watch window output
[image]
Please tell me why this give me false condition and how to solve it.

Comment: What is `str_char`? Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Hey @jon Steek i added full code please see it... thanks

Comment: No, that's not full code. That's part of a method. I can't compile it and run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str` variable has a length of 3, instead of 2, causing it to be different than `"MO"`.

Proof:

```
Dim decod As Decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder()
Dim totByt As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String("TU8=")
Dim chrCount As Integer = decod.GetCharCount(totByt, 0, totByt.Length)
Dim deco_char(chrCount) As Char
decod.GetChars(totByt, 0, totByt.Length, deco_char, 0)
Dim str As New String(deco_char)
Dim result1 = str.StartsWith("MO") ' is true
Dim result2 = str.Equals("MO") ' is false
Dim length = str.Length ' is 3
```

So obviously `str` is not the same as `"MO"`.

Remember that if you declare an array like:

```
 Dim deco_char(2) ' an array of 3 elements
```

...the indexes of the elements range from 0 through 2, so it contains 3 elements.

Solution: if you replace line 4 with:

```
 Dim deco_char(chrCount-1) As Char
```

.. it will work, because now (in your specific case) your array is of size 2 instead of 3.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the documentation for [String.Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and look at the possible values for 3rd parameter [comparisionType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
String.Equals("MO", str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Hi @Murali your code is not working in my case. Please check my updated question with watch window output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
str.Equals("MO", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```